# Unable to merge 2 JSON results and get response from a PHP script

Tags: php, json

I am trying to fetch a result from my select statement, I am using 2 statements and want a JDON response of the 2 outputs. That's all.

**Problem:** I am testing from Chrome Postman, it is showing result

```
[
null,
null
]
```

Below is my php code; where am I going wrong?

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-requested-with');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=900');
    header("Content-Type: application/json"); // tell client that we are sending json data

    define("DB_USR","erSKJV");
    define("DB_PsAS","T");
    define("DB","ipaddress/orcl.profits");
    $conn = oci_connect(DB_USR,DB_PAS,DB);

    if (!$conn) 
    {
        $e = oci_error();
        $result["message"] = $e['message'];
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit(1);
    } 

        $loggedinuser = $_POST['loggedinuser'];

        $stmt = "select count(*) as taskgiven from admtask where CLOSE_DT is null and primary='".$loggedinuser."' ";

        $stmt1 = "select count(*) as mytask from admtask where CLOSE_DT is null and entusr='".$loggedinuser."' ";

        $result=oci_parse($conn,$stmt);
        $ex2=oci_execute($result);

        while ($row=oci_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
          $stmta[] = $row;
        }
         json_encode($stmta);

        $result1=oci_parse($conn,$stmt1);
        $ex2=oci_execute($result1);

        while ($row1=oci_fetch_assoc($result1))
        {
          $stmtb[] = $row1;
        }
         json_encode($stmtb);

        $final[] = json_decode($stmta,true);
        $final[] = json_decode($stmtb,true);
        $json_merge = json_encode($final);

        echo json_encode($json_merge);


?>
```

You need to concentrate on stmta , stmtb and finally json_merge

Comment: check what does $stmta and $stmtb returns

Comment: if i `json_encode($stmta);` then it shows the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't call `json_encode()` on an array that contains JSON. Put the original arrays in the container array, and then call `json_encode()` on the entire thing.

```
$final = array($stmta, $stmtb);
echo json_encode($final);
```

Comment: trying the same, let you know the result very soon

Answer (score 0):

json_encode returns the string for the json. You need to assign that to a variable during the first two encodings.

```
while ($row=oci_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      $stmta[] = $row;
    }
    $stmta =  json_encode($stmta);

    $result1=oci_parse($conn,$stmt1);
    $ex2=oci_execute($result1);

    while ($row1=oci_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
      $stmtb[] = $row1;
    }
     $stmtb = json_encode($stmtb);
```

Comment: i use this code but it gives slashes between json data. how can i remove these slashes.

Comment: Post your result please

Comment: "[[{\"TASK\":\"25\"}],[{\"MYTASK\":\"80\"}]]"

Comment: STILL PROBLEM IS THERE